# Listing of Users who have viewed a file

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

Is there a way to view which users have actually viewed a file.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box the answer is No. You can add a JavaScript or similar on the pages that can log that kind of information. However you should be carefull as it might be a violation of GDPR or similar privacy regulations

Answer (score 1):

You can enable audit logs for this. This can be enabled at site collection level.

Go to site settings > Site collection audit settings under Site collection administration, then select the "Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties" option. You can take a look at the following article.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CorrelationId=03c99a70-a899-433a-a19c-c312967a8087&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US