# Programmatically extract who has viewed a shared file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I am wondering if there is a way to get at the list of users who have downloaded a file, programmatically, like the information that is already given to us over the web:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ6CC.png

I noticed this older post, but I am wondering if anyone is aware of ways to get at this information: [Listing of Users who have viewed a file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245494/listing-of-users-who-have-viewed-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Search the audit log in the compliance center, where you can check whether users download files and some other activities.

[Search the audit log in the compliance center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide)

A similar post for your reference:
[sharepoint audit logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439674/sharepoint-audit-logs-1.html)